# VueJS/Vuex: Cannot access to real value of input

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to change the `class` of my `input` if its current value is different from the binded **Vuex** value (knowing that the **Vuex** value will only be committed after the change is successfully sent with **axios** to a server, I'm also using **_debouce**, so there's always a delay).

My problem is that in `isEqual`, the value of `this.usualname` is always the same as the Vuex value it's associated with, it doesn't reflect the real state of the `input` value (while `currentValue` in `usualname` setter does).

How else can I retrieve the current value of my `input` in `isEqual` ? Or can I change the `input` `class` directly from `usualname` setter ?

My input is set as below:

```
<input type="text"
    v-model="usualname"
    @input="mymet(
        'company',
        $store.state.company_data.id,
        'usual_name',
        $event.target.value)"
    :class="isEqual ? 'form-control is-valid' : 'form-control is-invalid'">
```

In computed, I have this:

```
usualname: {
    get () {
        return this.$store.state.company_data.usual_name
    },
    set (currentValue) {
    }
},
isEqual: {
    get: function() {
        return this.usualname === this.$store.state.company_data.usual_name
    },
    set: function(value) {
    }
},
```

Comment: How about turning `usualname` a `data` field instead of a `computed`?

Comment: If I put `usualname: this.$store.state.company_data.usual_name` in `data()`, the `input` will not be initialized. Perhaps because the Vuex store is not yet ready when input value is set.

Comment: You have defined `usualname` to be equal to the store value. It cannot be anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Make `isEqual` a `data` item. In `usualname.set`, set it to false (you may have to check that the new value is not the same as the old value). Put a `watch` on `usualname` that sets it back to true.